# node - this.func() is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope, prototype, this

```
function Job(name, cronString, task) {
    "use strict";

    this.name = name;
    this.cronString = cronString;
    this.isReady = false;
    this.task = task;
}

Job.prototype.performTask = (db, winston) => {
     "use strict";
    const Promise = require("bluebird");
    let that = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let output = "";
        let success = true;

        try {
            output = that.task();
        }
        catch(error) {
            success = false;
            reject(error);
        }

        if(success) {
            resolve(output);
        }
    });
};

module.exports = Job;
```

Javascript newbie here. When I make a `Job` object and call the `performTask` method, I get "that.task is not a function". Shouldn't `this` at the very beginning of the `performTask` method refer to `Job`?
What is the mistake I'm making?
Also, is there a better way of doing what I'm trying to do here?

Comment: And where is your `Job.prototype.task` function?

Comment: @Overv It's passed in in the constructor function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the mistake I'm making?

You are using an arrow function. `this` inside arrow functions is resolved differently, it won't refer to your `Job` instance.

Do not use arrow functions for prototype methods.

Have a look at [Arrow function vs function declaration / expressions: Are they equivalent / exchangeable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34361379/218196) for more information.